# How to set space below button in dialog box for android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I am trying to make a beautiful dialog box with two buttons for my `Android` apps. My problem is there is no space below that buttons even I set `android:layout_marginBottom = 5dp`. The layout for this dialog box is `dialogbox.xml` as shown below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:background="@drawable/curve_shap"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_dia"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="Adakah anda ingin membatalkan permohonan anda ?"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center">
</TextView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#3E80B4">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pasti"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="Ya"
        android:textColor="#5DBCD2"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/takPasti"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="Tidak"
        android:textColor="#5DBCD2"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem ? This is the screenshot of dialog box when I run the code :

[image: Screenshot of Dialog box]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change as per below code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="80dp" //remove this
android:layout_height="wrap_content" //addthis
android:padding="10dp"//add this for space 
android:background="@drawable/curve_shap"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this change your main Root `LinearLayout` height

**You should use**

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

**instead of**

```
android:layout_height="80dp"
```

**change your layout like below code**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/curve_shap"
  android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but I think it will be much better if we set android:padding = "10dp" in LinearLayout. One more thing that I want to ask u, how do u put the image in question without using link ?